# How remove numbering from output after extract xls file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, extract

I have a Python Script that extracts a specific column from an Excel `.xls` file, but the output has a numbering next to the extracted information, so I would like to know how to format the output so that they don't appear.

My actual code is this:

```
for i in sys.argv:
    file_name = sys.argv[1]

workbook = pd.read_excel(file_name)
df = pd.DataFrame(workbook, columns=['NOM_LOGR_COMPLETO'])
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
print(df)
```

My current output:

```
1 Street Alpha <br>
2 Street Bravo
```

But the result I need is:

```
Street Alpha <br>
Street Bravo
```

without the numbering, just the name of the streets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want to have a dataframe without the index. Note that you cannot have a `DataFrame` without the indexes, they are the whole point of the `DataFrame`. So for your case, you can adopt:

```
print(df.values)
```

to see the dataframe without the index column. To save the output without index, use:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("dataframe.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = df, index=False)
writer.save()
```

where `file_name = "dataframe.xlsx"` for your case.

Further references can be found at:

[How to print pandas DataFrame without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index)

[Printing a pandas dataframe without row number/index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396477/printing-a-pandas-dataframe-without-row-number-index)

[disable index pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290123/disable-index-pandas-data-frame/29002199)

[Python to_excel without row names (index)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089317/python-to-excel-without-row-names-index)

Comment: @Vinicius Donatto If you find the solution useful and it solved your problem, it will be great if you can mark the answer as accepted. :) Otherwise do update the community and we can try our best to help further.

Comment: I combined the solution of the "Printing a pandas dataframe without row number/index" using the to_string function with your tip to print only the values ​​using "print (df.values)" setting index parameter to False and the result is very good, thanks!


my output code looks like this:
  `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: @ViniciusDonatto Thanks for the update! Glad it has helped you. :)

Comment: `index=False` from `to_excel` method did the trick on my end, thx!