# Export results to excel file title and link requests python

Tags: python, excel, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am training on how to scrape some data in python and here's my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://learndataanalysis.org/python-tutorial/page/10'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('h2.entry-title a')]
print(links)
```

The code gets the links of the webpage.
I can use this line to get the titles of each tutorial:

```
[i.text for i in soup.select('h2.entry-title a')]
```

How can I make a list of both the links and the titles and finally to export the results to excel file?

Simply I need a column for the titles of the articles and the other column for the link of each article.

Comment: @QHarr Can you have a look, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it with a single list comprehension.

Basically, what you have is the right approach, you just need to create a list of lists using your list comprehension.

For each match returned by `soup.select`, you can extract both the `text` and `href` together.

Then, using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, you can pass this list of lists to [`csv.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to create the CSV file for viewing in Excel or other tools, data processing, etc.

You can also optionally prepend a header to the list of lists, if you want, e.g. `['Title', 'URL']`.

Here is a full working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
import requests

url = 'https://learndataanalysis.org/python-tutorial/page/10'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = [[i.text, i['href']] for i in soup.select('h2.entry-title a')]

# optional, if you want to add a header line
data.insert(0, ['Title', 'URL'])

with open('output_data.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Note that `csv.QUOTE_ALL` isn't strictly necessary, but its often a good idea to force quoting on all fields.

---

If you instead want to export to an XLSX format, its best to use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) module instead:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title', 'URL'])
df.to_excel('output_data.xlsx')
```

This will by default also export the row numbers. If you prefer to omit them, you can use the [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) class, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959601/how-remove-numbering-from-output-after-extract-xls-file-with-pandas-python).

---

**Edit:**

If you want also want to extract the dates, then you can do so with a separate list comprehension (since the date information is in a different HTML element altogether).

Then, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the information together.

```
data = [[i.text, i['href']] for i in soup.select('h2.entry-title a')]
dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('span.published')]
data = [i + [j] for i, j in zip(data, dates)]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. I will study the code carefully so as to learn new skills which I don't know.

Comment: Is it possible to use comprehension to add a third item. I mean what if I need to add the date of the article by editing this line `data = [[i.text, i['href']] for i in soup.select('h2.entry-title a')]`?

Comment: @yasserkhalil sure, I've updated the answer to also extract the dates.

Comment: What if the dates are in the same HTML element? I wish to know if it is possible to deal with multiple cases in one comprehension?

Comment: @yasserkhalil Sure, it would work the same way, instead of `[i.text, i['href']]` it would be something like `[i.text, i['href'], extra]` for any `extra` field you want. Each inner list becomes a row of the file, and you can add as many columns as you need.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Best Regards